# How to create a custom field formatter?

Tags: 8, hooks, media

I look for create custom field image widget with image styles for drupal 8.

I need something like that:

```
// Here for example with a "Large preset"
<div class="wrap1"> 
    <div class="item"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
</div>

// Here  same images but with a "Thumbnail preset" 
<div class="wrap2">  
    <div class="item"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

I read this https://www.drupal.org/node/2620966 but still don’t understand how to applicate it for my objective. P.S. I mean to make it in a custom module.

I don’t have any idea how to make it. I’ll very thankful for any help!

Comment: Is this for the node edit form? or when you view the node?

Comment: When i view the node

Comment: In that case, a non coding solution, would be to create a block view. Add the image field twice to your view field and style each of them differently. Then insert the block view to your node.

Comment: How about overriding the field template?

Comment: yes i thought about overriding the field template, but i cant found any example.

Comment: @JimmyKo possible, but how would he change the image style without having to add another image field?

Comment: @No Sssweat you could copy `items` in field preprocess and change in the copy the styling of the images. Then you could put two different item loops in the field template.

Comment: @4k4 it's seems like what I'm searching, can you please show me any example?

Comment: No, only this idea right now. But go ahead and if there are any problems at some point ask another question, as we are now have another topic.